# rm only for working tree, only for files in git

Tags: git, version-control, development-environment

Git-scm.org is pretty clear on their website that `git rm` cannot be used to remove files from ONLY the working tree. From [git-scm.org](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

> There is no option to remove a file only from the working tree and yet
>   keep it in the index; use /bin/rm if you want to do that.

My question is: Is there a way I can do this anyway? Not strictly with `git rm` per se.

The reason I want to do this is that I have two folders in my (C#) development workflow- the web root and my dev root. When I build my project, all the project files get copied over from the dev root to the web root. As siblings of those project files, I have a large CMS framework in the web root. Those are installed once and live side-by-side with my project files.

The issue with this workflow is that if I change the location of a file, or I rename a file, there is no removal of the old file. The process is a bulk copy, and I will have two versions of one file that I want to manage in my web root. This leads to confusing errors.

My idea is to use a local git repository in my web root, with a .gitignore for all the CMS framework files. I want to build a script that performs three operations:

1. Removes all git-controlled files
2. Copies files from the dev root to the web root
3. Add any changes to the index, commit them.

This way I'm guaranteed for my web root to never be polluted by stale files. This also opens the door for a few more opportunities that I want to explore.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241850/get-deleted-files-list-from-git-commits/31242006#31242006 - maybe there's something to help you there. `rsync` should take care of what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is a good approach is debatable, but I did hack something together that works:

`for /f "tokens=4" %a in ('git ls-tree --full-name -r HEAD') DO rm %a`